# How to add images from drawable folder to FrescoImageViewer?

Tags: android, arraylist, fresco

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageViewer Fresco;

    Integer[] images = {R.drawable.b1, R.drawable.b2, R.drawable.b3, R.drawable.b4, R.drawable.b5, R.drawable.b6, R.drawable.b7, R.drawable.b8, R.drawable.b9, R.drawable.b10};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        new ImageViewer.Builder(MainActivity.this, images)
                .setStartPosition(R.drawable.b1)
                .show();


    }
}
```

I try sample from the git :: https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer

Answer (score 1):

get your all drawable you want by their path! as a string because  ImageViewer requires list or array of only String (i.e. urls of the images!)

get url for each image by doing this like! these

```
    String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
or
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.rizwan.appo.gappo/" + R.drawable.naruto_img);
    String url1= path.toString();
or
    Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.rizwan.appo.gappo/drawable/naruto_img");
    String url2= otherPath .toString();


ImageViewer Fresco;

    String[] images = {url1,url2,.......};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        new ImageViewer.Builder(MainActivity.this, images)
                .setStartPosition(R.drawable.b1)
                .show();


    }
}
```

Comment: i showed a few different ways to get path to your desired drawable just lemme know which one works better in mine case all work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
mSimpleDraweeView.setImageURI(UriUtil.getUriForResourceId(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```